# Flow analysis doesn't work when using setState

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
void f() {
  String string;
  setState(() {
    string = fooCondition ? 'foo' : 'bar';
  });
  
  string.toUpperCase(); // Error
}
```

If I remove the `setState` condition, the flow analysis work! I could put my `setState` below (blank `setState(() {}`) but that just reduce the readability of code. Is there any better way of doing it without making the `string` nullable and checking for nullability thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you can also use `late` keyword in local scope.

```
late String string;
```

To answer your question:

```dart
void f() {
  late String string;
  setState(() {
    string = fooCondition ? 'foo' : 'bar';
  });

  string.toUpperCase(); // Works
}
```